# Output in makefile at top-level

Tags: makefile, warnings

I am setting a variable in a `makefile` like this:

```
SOMEVAR = foo
```

This makefile later includes some other `makefile` in which the actual building of programs takes place:

```
include generic/Makefile.common
```

So no build targets are defined in the first `makefile`, it's only setting up variables which are then used by the common generic `makefile` to do the actual package building.

Now I know that I should be careful when using `foo`, so to remind myself of this, I want to print a warning message whenever this makefile is used to setup the make process. The problem is that I cannot just insert an `echo` command after the variable definition, because we are not yet building something there.

Is there a solution (more elegant than adding a fake target where the message is printed which would destroy the separation of setting variables and building)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SOMEVAR = foo
$(warning be careful with foo)
```

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig: No? What version of Make are you using?

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig: I am using GNUMAKE 3.81 also. I don't know how to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig: Wait-- are you getting an error message, that Make does not know what `warning` means, or does it do nothing?

Answer (score 9):

According with [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html) there is three ways to do a top-level output in a makefile

1. $(error text)
2. $(warning text)
3. $(info text)

Just in case you want do that in another way.

I hope helps.